# Android Maven Plugin: NPE in AndroidSdk.getPathForBuildTool

Tags: java, android, maven, maven-3, android-maven-plugin

I've created a simple Android project using the [Android Quickstart Archetype](http://stand.spree.de/wiki_details_maven_archetypes) (`pom.xml` see below).

When I run `mvn -e clean compile`, I get following error:

```
  [ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:andr
oid-maven-plugin:3.8.2:generate-sources (default-generate-sources) on project in
wt-android: Execution default-generate-sources of goal com.jayway.maven.plugins.
android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.8.2:generate-sources failed. NullPoin
terException -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal c
om.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.8.2:generate-
sources (default-generate-sources) on project myproduct: Execution default-ge
nerate-sources of goal com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-mave
n-plugin:3.8.2:generate-sources failed.
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:224)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProje
ct(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProje
ct(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThre
adedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(Lifecycl
eStarter.java:120)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:347)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:154)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Laun
cher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.jav
a:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(La
uncher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:
356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-g
enerate-sources of goal com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-mav
en-plugin:3.8.2:generate-sources failed.
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(Default
BuildPluginManager.java:143)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:208)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.AndroidSdk.getPathForBuildTool(Andro
idSdk.java:251)
        at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.AndroidSdk.getAaptPath(AndroidSdk.ja
va:157)
        at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.phase01generatesources.GenerateSourc
esMojo.generateR(GenerateSourcesMojo.java:585)
        at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.phase01generatesources.GenerateSourc
esMojo.execute(GenerateSourcesMojo.java:216)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(Default
BuildPluginManager.java:132)
        ... 20 more
```

How can I fix it?

Here's my `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>co.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>myproduct-android</artifactId>
    <version>co.mycompany.myproduct.android</version>
    <packaging>apk</packaging>
    <name>myproduct-android</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <platform.version> 4.1.1.4
            </platform.version>
        <android.plugin.version>3.8.2</android.plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <version>${platform.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                    <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${android.plugin.version}</version>
                    <extensions>true</extensions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <sdk>
                        <platform>16</platform>
                        <path>C:\Program Files\adt-bundle-windows-x86\adt-bundle-windows-x86\sdk</path>
                    </sdk>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Same here, happens within a Jenkins build.